# High power boost converter circuit issue

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, dc-dc-converter, solid-state-relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCyWy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I made a dc-dc booster converter circuit.

With a 3 mF capacitor, 48V can be boosted to 200V in 0.5 seconds.
But for some reason, circuit will short when the DC input voltage is higher the 18 V (SSRopen).
Only run normal when the DC input turning off (MCU always working fine).

I think no components damaged from the issue. Because DC input under 18 V is working.

MCU I used for a1, a2 signal to control SSR is teensy 4.0.
DC input I use a adjustable power supply.
V beside the capacitor is an analog voltage meter.

Please help me solve it.

I think the inductor or some noise affects the transistor when boosting, but I don't know why or how to avoid it.

Because the SSR control pin remains at 12 volts on error.
Turn normal when DC input turning off.

[image]

[image: L1]

Comment: Welcome! I can't read your handwriting. Please use the built in schematic tool by clicking on edit and the schematic symbol. Link to all relevant component datasheets.

Comment: Maybe a SSR is not "tune" for such a purpose. There can be an oscillation on right side of inductor (on schematic) so the voltage on SSR can be too high or negative causing SSR to fail. 80mH you probably wound by yourself, right? Can you show it?

Comment: thank you,i update the figure of inductor.

Comment: This inductor (with air core) does not have 80mH. So the SSR fail because of overcurrent, i.e. current rises too fast after SSR turns on. At 100Hz you need to put a silicon steel core inside an inductor to get enough inductance.

Comment: Why are you trying to build a boost converter with SSRs in the first place? Why not plain regular MOSFETs?

Comment: Because τ=L/R. So increase inductance can make more time for current.To reduce the peak current,is that the theory?

Comment: What behaves the power supply after fail? Regarding the Tau you are right.

Comment: At first i used mosfet,but the project need higher power.So I used to damage the mosfet due to the high voltage and current.

Comment: If DC input keep supply voltage,SSR will keep short the dc-in、out.
Back to normal when i turn off the power supply.

Comment: Can you try to connect a 1k resistor between Q1 collector and Gnd? It should pull-down the SSR input when Q1 signal is off.

Comment: And what is the reason of SSR2? Did you try to avoid it?

Comment: OK, I'll try. SSR2 is used to isolate the power supply. it may not be the only channel.

Comment: I added a 1k resistor between contro+ and Gnd.Seems no difference.I think i should change inductor or change freqency of a1.

Comment: Reducing R1 might be another way.

Comment: Why would you use an SSR for this? You can get much higher-power MOSFETs than SSRs....

Comment: Any suggestion with same(75m ohm) or lower resistence?